# How to connect local git to remote git repo

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control

for ex:
username = `demodev`
servername = `servername.com`
created git repo in server punlic_html/sample.git.

`using git commend : git remote set-url origin https://demodev@servername.com/home/demodev/public_html/sample.git/`

after the git remote commend

git push origin master

it will show some error msg

`fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://demodev@servername.com/home/demodev/public_html/waqtpar.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
   redirect: https://servername.com/404.html`

Comment: You can test by `git clone https://demodev@servername.com/home/demodev/public_html/sample.git` to check if the URL is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the

> /

sign from the end of the url.

Comment: yes now i removed the / in end of the remote url but still comes

fatal: repository 'http://demodev@servername.com/home/demodev/public_html/waqtpar.git/' not found

What to do ? :(

Comment: This is a web server, or is it on your local network?